# Save and read file with stream on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, inputstream, dataoutputstream

Argument 'address' is the string "CepVizyonVersionFile", and after `Connector.openDataInputStream(address)` the program throws an exception with message:

> no ' : ' in URL.

What format should address be in?

```
public void saveLocal(String fileString, String address) {
        try {
            DataOutputStream fos = Connector.openDataOutputStream(address); //openFileOutput(address);
            fos.write(fileString.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public String readLocal(String address, int lenght) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[lenght];
    byte[] buffer2;
    String str = new String();
    try {
        DataInputStream fis = Connector.openDataInputStream(address);
        int lnght = fis.read(buffer);
        buffer2 = new byte[lnght];
        fis.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < lnght; i++)
            buffer2[i] = buffer[i];
        str = new String(buffer2);
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlackBerry API documentation for [Connector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html) has an explanation of the format:

> The parameter string that describes the target should conform to the URL format as described in RFC 2396. This takes the general form:
>   {scheme}:[{target}][{parms}]
>   where {scheme} is the name of a protocol such as http.
>
> The {target} is normally some kind of network address.
>
> Any {parms} are formed as a series of equates of the form ";x=y". Example: ";type=a".

and the supported schemes are listed as well:

> comm
>   socket
>   udp
>   sms
>   mms
>   http
>   https
>   tls or ssl
>   Bluetooth Serial Port Profile

Since you want a file, you'll need to take a look at the package documentation for [javax.microedition.io.file](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/package-summary.html)

> The format of the input string used to access a FileConnection through Connector.open() must follow the format for a fully qualified, absolute path file name as described in the file URL format as part of IETF RFCs 1738 & 2396. That RFC dictates that a file URL takes the form:
>
> `file://<host>/<path>`

Comment: ok if I want to files are ınvısıble for other apps and user, what should I dO?

Comment: @atasoyh That sounds like a distinct question - open a new question on StackOverflow for it.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you put your file?
 If it is on the media card, your address should be like this: "file:///SDCard/"+yourfilename.